# Foreach - listview

Tags: asp.net, linq, listview, foreach

I have List view - (

> name: ListViewName

), with some labels inside it, the ID (name) of the label:

> Biglbl

.. big because its include some links and titles.

there is one more label in name:

> lblCatName

which return the category name.

I want to check each list view item - what is name (let's say - "TEST") and hide or display some labels or change HyperLink navigateUrl.

aspx:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListViewName" OnItemDataBound="ContactsListView_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label Visible="true"  ID="lblCName" Text='<%# Eval("CatName") %>' runat="server" > </asp:Label>

  <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblCName" Visible="false" />
              <div style=".....">

       ...............


         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" 
      NavigateUrl='<%# "bla.aspx?Id=" + Eval("id").ToString() %>'> 


                  </asp:HyperLink>

         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server" 
      NavigateUrl='<%# "bla.aspx?Id=" + Eval("CatId").ToString() %>'>  <img src="images/btblue.png" /> </asp:HyperLink>

    </asp:Label>  

    </div>


        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

I have the C# code behind:

```
protected void ContactsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender,ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
            foreach (ListViewItem item in ListViewName.Items)
        {

            Biglbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Biglbl");
            Label lblCName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCatName");

            HyperLink Link = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink4");
            HyperLink Link2 = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink7");

            if (lblCatName.ToString() == "TEST")
            {
                Biglbl.Visible = true;
                Link.NavigateUrl = "blabla";
                Link2.NavigateUrl = "blabla";
            }
            else
            {
                Biglbl.Visible = false;
                Link.NavigateUrl = "aaaa";
                Link2.NavigateUrl = "aaaa";
            }

        }
}
```

I don't know how to use the foreache for my needs here.

What i need to do (i think the if and the findcontrol's are fine.. i need to do what to change in the foreac.

Comment: please , clarify what do u want ?I can't even edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: I have listview, with 2 labels ok? the id of the labels shown in the question.  the BigLabel include many code - it's not important what. there is lblcatName that return some text. i want to check the name the lblcatName have, and if it's TEST - so display only the relevant info in the listview.

Comment: I'v edit the question. appologize for the mess, i removed many code from the aspx for the question.

Comment: finally @benni_mac_b was right, so he understood my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in ListViewName.Items)
{
  // Code goes here.
}
```

**EDIT**: I see the question now shows you using `ItemDataBound`. This will pass you each `ListViewItem` as it is bound so there is no need to do a for each loop.

You can simply cast the sender to that type

```
ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)sender;
```

Comment: What need to be instead "item" ? or it must be stay as is - item?

Comment: 'item' is just a name that you use for that particular ListViewItem whilst in the for each loop. item could easily be renamed 'e' or 'myItem' or 'Bob'

Comment: thanks it's work :)
i made: ListViewItem item = e.Item as ListViewItem;